# Class template parameter inference with constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class :

```
template <typename T>
struct timer
{
    T period;

    timer(T p) :
        period(p)
    {}
};
```

To instantiate it I need to do :

```
timer<double> t(double(0.0));
```

Is is possible to improve `timer`'s class definition to allow this syntax :

```
timer t(double(0.0));
```

and have the compiler infer the `double` type from the constructor's argument ?

Comment: check out [Why not infer template parameter from constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor) for the same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Type inference doesn't occur in those situations. You could use the `auto` keyword and a function template to make things easier though:

```
template<typename T>
timer<T> make_timer(T value) {
    return value;
}

// let the compiler deduce double
auto t = make_timer(0.0);
```

Note that this use of the `auto` keyword is only valid in the C++11 standard.

Moreover, for this specific situation, you could `typedef` a `double` timer:

```
typedef timer<double> timer_d;

timer_d t(0.0);
```

Though I'd still go with the first solution, if you're able to use C++11.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible, deduction only works in functions. The usual solution is to write a `make_` function which returns a new instance. This is C++11:

```
template <typename T>
timer<T> make_timer(T&& p) {
  return timer<T>(std::forward<T>(p));
}

auto t = make_timer(0.0);
```