# C++ - Is it possible to instantiate a `vector` without specifying the type?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

So basic, but hard to search that in Google for me.

I am doing a C++ training course online and the topic is STL; in this case `vector`.

**Is it possible to instantiate a `vector` without specifying the type?**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector v1(10, 0);
    cout<<"Size: "<<v1.size()<<endl;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<< v1[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think that is wrong, but I see that throughout the course and this confuses me.

When use `vector<int> v1(10, 0)` then it compiles, and that is how it should be I think.

In the course we are using NetBeans, but I don't think there is a config or parameter or anything that can make that happen, is there?

Comment: No it's not possible, you have to specify the type.

Comment: No, you can't deduce class template arguments from a constructor. There are some proposals for such a feature, but they're highly controversial.

Comment: You can have an alias that will make the above code compile.(e.g. typedef std::vector<int> vector;)  but I suspect it is not what you were asking.

Comment: You van full it with a boost::any I suppose, but that's hardly the same...

Comment: In theory, you could define an alias by `using vector = std::vector<int>;` and then use `vector` instead of `std::vector<int>`.  But it wouldn't work in your case as it would introduce an ambiguity with the `using namespace std;`.  But you could say `using numbervector = std::vector<int>;` or however you like to call it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight As Kerrek said, deduce it from the ctor args, specifically the `val` argument to the fill ctor. `auto` does something similar, after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Templates in general

Ignoring the details of `std::vector` for the moment, it *is* possible to define a default type for a template parameter of a class template. For example:

```
template <class T = int>
class foo { 
    T *bar;
};
```

In such a case, you don't *have* to specify a type to instantiate that template. At the same time, you *do* have to include a template parameter list. The trick is that the list can be empty, so you could instantiate this template in any of the following ways:

```
foo<long> a; // instantiate over long. The `int` default is just ignored
foo<int>  b; // instantiate over int. Still doesn't use default
foo<>     c; // also instantiates over int
```

#### `std::vector` specifically

`std::vector` does use a default parameter for the type of the allocator, but does not provide a default for the type being stored, so the definition looks something like this:

```
template <class T, class allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class vector
// ...
```

So, if you don't specify otherwise, the allocator type for the vector will be an `std::allocator` instantiated over the same type as you're storing--but you *do* always have to specify a type you're storing, because no default is provided for that type.

#### Summary

It is definitely possible to specify defaults for all the parameters to a template, in which case it's possible to instantiate the template without (explicitly) specifying the type at the instantiation--but `std::vector` has one template parameter for which no default is provided, so to instantiate `vector`, you must specify a type for that parameter.

Answer (score 9):

C++17 does support instantiation of vectors without type. Please see this article, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

for more information.

So, for instance writing this will work:

```
vector v {1, 2, 3};  // instead of vector<int>
```

if you compile with this "-std=c++17" flag.

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the type because it is not inferred from the parameters of the constructor. However, nobody forbids you to do this

```
std::vector<int> make_vector(std::vector<int>::size_type n, int val)
{
      return std::vector<int>(n, val);
}

// ...
auto v2 = make_vector(10, 0);
```

As why this is not possible, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor) question and related ones.

Comment: hmm interesting, given functions _can_ deduce template arguments you could extend this by templating on the value type. Something like:

`template <typename size_type, typename value_type> std::vector<vaule_type> make_vector(size_type size, value_type val) { ... }`

Comment: @PeterSW `size_type` doesn't need (and shouldn't) be a template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

No, `std::vector` is a template and cannot be instantiated without specifying the template parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible (with a different setup):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using vector = std::vector<int>;

int main()
{
    vector v1(10, 0);
    cout<<"Size: "<<v1.size()<<endl;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<< v1[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note, use 'using' carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Beside it being a syntax error, a vector without a type would be logically meaningless.  You are asking for a list, but a list of nothing...  What exactly were you expecting it to print out?

Comment: It's a code sample from a course. I could not compile it because of said *error*.