# map Comparison Constructor Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, comparator, constructorargument

Is there a reason why I cannot pass a comparison functor to a `map` as a constructor argument:

```
map<int, string, greater<int>> foo;
//map<int, string> foo(greater<int>()); Doesn't work
```

Or why I cannot pass a lambda without providing my own comparison type:

```
map<int, string, function<bool(const int&, const int&)>> bar([](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; });
//map<int, string> bar([](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; }); Doesn't work
```

I'd like to just be able to declare `map<int, string>` and construct it with a comparator. Why can't I?

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/iCfG8n)]

Comment: Because that would involve some type-erasing, which is not optimal?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why not infer template parameter from constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You're saying that for the functor version? But doesn't `map` provide a comparison constructor? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/ Isn't that exactly what this is for?

Comment: @JonathanMee it's used to initialize the actual comparator stored in a map. how would you store that comparator without knowing its type outside of the constructor

Comment: @NathanOliver You're saying that we have to have the type in the `map` template because we could just use a pointer?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes.  How would you know what kind of map it is?  Remember a template class is not a class it is a recipe.  We need to know at compile time which kind of map to make and having a pointer an initializing it a run time would circumvent that.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I see what you're saying. I'm thinking of functors as though they are `bool operator(const int&, const int&)` functions, but in fact `less` and `greater` are completely different structs. That sounds like a reasonable answer if you want to post it.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I have gone ahead and posted an answer of what I extrapolated from your comments. If you feel like posting an answer let me know, and I'll remove mine to defer to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question stems from a misconception. To clear that up:

**Functors are objects *not* functions**

Trying to assign a function pointer or a lambda to an object doesn't make any sense. So this cannot be done: <strike>`map<int, string> bar([](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; });`</strike> The way to define a `map` which takes a function pointer or lambda is to use the template arguments from the question: `map<int, string, function<bool(const int&, const int&)>>`

Halfway between the two ill-conceived options in the question is another misconception: <strike>`map<int, string, [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; }>`</strike> Doesn't work because the comparator template argument is the *type* of a member of `map`, *not* the intialization value. **So a `map` using a function pointer or lambda comparator must always have that value passed to the `map` constructor: `map<int, string, function<bool(const int&, const int&)>> bar([](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; })`** Otherwise `function<bool(const int&, const int&)>()` would be used for comparisons in the `map`.

This is probably already clear by now, but since functors are objects you cannot pass an unrelated object is the construction value of a completely different type of object. Calling <strike>`map<int, string> foo(greater<int>())`</strike> is like calling <strike>`less<int> foo = greater<int>`</strike>. **The only acceptable compatator constructor argument to a `map` whose comparator template argument is a functor is something that can be converted into an object of the functor type in the template argument: `map<int, string, greater<int>> foo(greater<int>{})`** This is obviously unnecessary, because if no argument was provided and the `greater<int>` was default constructed the same member initialization of the `map` would result, so `map<int, string, greater<int>>` is sufficent.

Comment: `map<int, string, greater<int>> foo(greater<int>())` is a function declaration (most vexing parse)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Ugh, thanks. Obviously I didn't try that cause it's kinda pointless. I've edited, and actually tested that it works now: http://ideone.com/1Ygrze