# What Is a Curly-Brace Enclosed List If Not an intializer_list?

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list, initializer, curly-braces

I asked a question here: [Lifetime Extension of a initializer_list return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37656076/2642059) involving the non-functional code:

```
const auto foo = [](const auto& a, const auto& b, const auto& c) { return {a, b, c}; };
```

I believed the lambda was trying to return an `intializer_list` (that's bad, don't do that.) But I got a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656076/lifetime-extension-of-a-initializer-list-return?noredirect=1#comment62791567_37656076):

> It's not an `initializer_list`, it's an initializer list. Two different things.

I just thought that any time you did a curly-braced list you were creating an `intializer_list`. If that's not what's happening, what is a list in curly-braces?

Comment: It's just: error: returning initializer list.

Comment: @DieterLücking You must have your errors turned up higher than I do. I didn't even get a warning the first time I tried this, though as stated in the linked question this is *not* good code.

Comment: @JonathanMee Below SO question has also some useful-to-know answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200036/is-providing-a-private-constructor-for-initializer-list-conforming

Comment: @Arunmu Are you saying these are just good to know related to `initializer_list`? Cause if you're saying it directly pertains, I'm missing how.

Comment: @JonathanMee Yeah, just good to know :). I had no idea there was some compiler magic required to make initializer_list instances :)

Comment: @op could you do something about the Title Case in your question's title? It's not improving readability.

Comment: @user1306322 If you can cite a http://www.stackoverflow.com standard for titles I'll fix this and all future titles. I'm using [Title Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles) which I thought was standard.

Comment: I could google up something about capital letters disrupting the readability, but it's all subjective and there's no "official" standards on it on the internet. Just my observation. If you disagree, I'm not gonna argue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three distinct, but related concepts here:

1. *braced-init-list*: The grammatical rule associated with curly-brace-enclosed lists in certain contexts.
2. Initializer list: The name for the *braced-init-list* initializer used in *list-initialization*.
3. `std::initializer_list`: A class wrapping a temporary array which is created in some contexts involving *braced-init-list*s.

Some examples:

```
//a braced-init-list and initializer list, 
//but doesn't create a std::initializer_list
int a {4}; 

//a braced-init-list and initializer list,
//creates a std::initializer_list
std::vector b {1, 2, 3};

//a braced-init-list and initializer list,
//does not create a std::initializer_list (aggregate initialization)
int c[] = {1, 2, 3};

//d is a std::initializer_list created from an initializer list
std::initializer_list d {1, 2, 3};

//e is std::initializer_list<int>
auto e = { 4 };

//f used to be a std::initializer_list<int>, but is now int after N3922
auto f { 4 };
```

You might want to read [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html), which changed some of the rules involving `auto` and `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 30):

It is an *braced-init-list*.  A *braced-init-list* existed before `std::initializer_list` and is used to [initialize aggregates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

The above used a *braced-init-list* to initialize the array, no `std::initializer_list` is created.  On the other hand when you do

```
std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

`foo` is not an aggregate so the *braced-init-list* is used to create a `std::initializer_list` which is in turned passed to the constructor of `foo` that accepts a `std::initializer_list`.

A thing to note about a *braced-init-list* is that is has no type so special rules were developed for use with it and `auto`.  It has the following behavior (since the adoption of [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html))

```
auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x5{ 3 }; // decltype(x5) is int
```

And you can get more information on history of this behavior and why it was changed at: [Why does auto x{3} deduce an initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612262/why-does-auto-x3-deduce-an-initializer-list)

Comment: So if I do, `auto foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` what is the type of `foo`? Is it guaranteed to be an `intializer_list`?

Comment: @JonathanMee I think the update should cover that now.

Comment: @T.C. I don't even see the word "nonterminal" what are you talking about there?

Comment: @JonathanMee What do you think *braced-init-list* is?

Comment: @T.C. Well before today I thought it was an `initializer_list` ;) I guess you're telling me that "nonterminal" is another name for it?

Comment: @JonathanMee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols *braced-init-list* is the nonterminal symbol for this construct in the C++ grammar.

Comment: @T.C. I understand some of the words in that article.

Answer (score 7):

> I just thought that any time you did a curly-braced list you were creating an `intializer_list`.

That's not correct.

> If that's not what's happening, what is a list in curly-braces?

```
struct Foo {int a; int b;};
Foo f = {10, 20};
```

The `{10, 20}` part is not an `initializer_list`. It's just a syntactic form to use a list of objects to create another object.

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
```

Once again, it's a syntactic form to create an array.

The name for the syntactic form is [*`braced-init-list`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: So same question I asked, @NathanOliver: "If I do, `auto foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` what is the type of `foo`? Is it guaranteed to be an `intializer_list`?"

Comment: That will be a `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different things when use `{}`

1. A Type `std::initializer_list<T>` where the values can be implicitly converted to `T`
2. A type that can be initialized with the values of the list.

The first type forces a homogeneous list and the second type don't. In the next example:

```
struct S{ 
    int a; 
    string b 
};

void f1( S s );
void f2( int i );
void f3( std::initializer_list<int> l );

f1( {1, "zhen"} ); // construct a temporal S
f2( {1} );         // construct a temporal int
f3( {1,2,3} );     // construct a temporal list of ints
```

The functions f1 and f2 use the first type and f3 use the second type. You should know that if there is ambiguity, the std::initializer_list is prefered. E.g:

```
void f( S s );
void f( int i );
void f( std::initializer_list<int> l );

f( {1, "zhen"} ); // calls with struct S
f( {1} );         // calls with int list with one element
f( {1,2,3} );     // calls with int list with three elements
```