# C++ Initializing a vector inside a struct definition

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, struct

I'm reading through Programming Principles and Practice C++, and came across the following piece of code which I don't think was well explained

```
struct Day {
    vector<double> hour{vector<double>(24,-777) };
};
```

What is happening here? I usually use this initializer when I need a vector of a certain length with default values:

```
vector<double> hour(24, -777);
```

However, this way of initializing does not work inside the struct,

```
struct Day {
    vector<double> hour(24, -777);
};
```

Results in a compile error

```
Error (active)      expected a type specifier   HelloWorld  d:\Visual Studio 2015\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.cpp  11  
Error (active)      expected a type specifier   HelloWorld  d:\Visual Studio 2015\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.cpp  11  
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'constant'    HelloWorld  d:\visual studio 2015\helloworld\helloworld\helloworld.cpp  11
```

Looking for an explanation behind the initializers.

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2015

Comment: What do you mean by _initializing does not work inside the struct_? Maybe it's unsupported syntax by VS? It compiles fine [here](https://ideone.com/fLXQ82).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It also compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40888321/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee That's why I asked for clarification, why did the OP mean by _does not work_, and I don't have MSVS 2015 at my disposal, so I couldn't test it myself. In addition to that, I have seen functionality differ for different update versions, of the same major version MSVS, so without specifying those, it's unclear if you are using the same version of MSVS (even though it's MSVS2015).

Comment: Apologies for lack of details, can you please see the edits?

Comment: @AdrianMuljadi That doesn't work because C++ doesn't support that syntax for class member declaration. You can learn more about the requirements for default member initialization in part **2** of my answer.

Comment: @AdrianMuljadi Just FYI, if you want to communicate via comment on http://www.stackoverflow.com you should use "@" followed by the username that way the person you're communicating with will be notified of a new message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<double>(24,-777)
```

This creates a temporary `std::vector` with 24 values of `-777`.

Then the `hour` vector is constructed by using that temporary, using the move constructor.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's a `constexpr` `vector`. [The resulting code is without a temporary](https://godbolt.org/g/20NX6k).

Comment: Thanks, have you got a reading resource about temporaries, and move constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Visual Studio 2015: http://rextester.com/WIS16088 Perhaps you're doing something else wrong in your code?

Anyway to explain what's going on here:

1. The behavior of curry braces here was clarified in [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) which in this case will distill to a braced-init-list, there is some great further reading here: [What Is a Curly-Brace Enclosed List If Not an intializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37682392/2642059)
2. These curly braces are providing [default member initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for the member `hours`, as provided by C++11. This is the value that `hours` will take on unless it:

> Also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor

3. Finally let's talk about the value that is being used in the curly braces which is `hours` brace-init-list, that's clearly a `vector<int>` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector defines that as the 2<sup>nd</sup> constructor which:

> Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value

So what you'll end up with is `hours` initialized to contain 24 `int`s of value -777 if it is default initialized.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 lifted restrictions on in-class initialization and introduced initializer_list constructors for collections allowing you to write this:

```
struct Day {
    std::vector<double> hours = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
};
```

However for your case (vector filled with 24 values of -777.0), you don't want initializer_list - you still can use old constructor, but unfortunately you can't combine it with `auto` (unless it's `static constexpr` literal member). You should probably use 24u to parameter, that's intended to be converted to `size_t` and `double` for parameter intended to be value (for readability):

```
struct Day {
    std::vector<double> hours = std::vector<double>(24u, -777.);
};
```

Example with using `auto` to initialize some member:

```
struct Day {
    static constexpr auto default_hours_size = 24u;
    std::vector<double> hours = std::vector<double>(default_hours_size, -777.);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution should be valid. If it does not work, try doing this:

```
struct Day {
    vector<double> hour = vector<double>(24,7);
};
```

Comment: The initialization syntax used in the question is already valid in Visual Studio 2015, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40888321/2642059 So no changes need to be made, that said this does not attempt to address the actual question of: "What is happening here?"