# Can i instantiate an array from an initializer_list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

So i can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
main(){   
    auto init = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v(init);
}
```

and i can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
main(){   
    int i[3] = {1,2,3};
}
```

Why can i not do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
main(){   
    auto init = {1,2,3};
    int i[3] = init;
}
```

?

the compiler tells me this:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:16: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed 
initializer
     int i[3] = init;
                ^~~~

exit status 1
```

it does not make a difference if i create `init` with `std::initializer_list<int>` instead of `auto`.

You can mess around with it [here](https://repl.it/Jc3u).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `auto init = {1,2,3};` you get a `std::initialized_list`.  This is not the same as just `{1,2,3}` which is a *braced-init-list*.  You can initialize an array with a *braced-init-list* as it is an aggregate but you cannot use a `std::initialized_list` as that requires a constructor.

Comment: aah, so `{1,2,3}` is not actually an `std::initializer_list`, but a *braced-init-list*, and there is a constructor that gives me a `std::initializer_list` from that. Can i create an instance of a *braced-init-list*?

Comment: @will No you cannot have a object that is a *braced-init-list*  They can only be used to initialize things.

Comment: @will here is a good related read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682392/what-is-a-curly-brace-enclosed-list-if-not-an-intializer-list