# Curly braces constructor prefers initializer_list over better match. Why?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <vector>

using std::size_t;

struct Foo
{
    Foo(size_t i, char c) {}
};

Foo Bar1()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    char c = 'x';
    return { i, c }; // good
}

std::vector<char> Bar2()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    char c = 'x';
    return { i, c }; // bad
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/87uD1ikpMkThPTaw

> warning: narrowing conversion of 'i' from 'std::size_t {aka long
>   unsigned int}' to 'char' inside { }

Obviously it tries to use the initializer_list of vector. But why doesn't it use the better match `vector<char>(size_t, char)` ?

Can i use the desired constructor in a return statement without writing the type again?

Comment: See for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), that after the special cases for aggregate types and empty braced-init-lists, it considers `std::initializer_list` constructors before other constructor overloads.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37682392/2642059

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because initializer_list constructors, if at all possible, take precedence over other constructors. This is to make edge cases less confusing - specifically, this particular vector constructor that you expect it to use was deemed too easily selected by accident.

Specifically, the standard says in 16.3.1.7 "Initialization by list-initialization" [over.match.list] (latest draft, N4687):

> (1) When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such that 11.6.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (11.6.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

So if you do `std::vector<char>( i, c )`, this section does not apply at all, since it isn't list-initialization. Normal overload resolution is applied, the `(size_t, char)` constructor is found, and used.

But if you do `std::vector<char>{ i, c }`, this is list-initialization. The initializer list constructors are tried first, and the `(initializer_list<char>)` constructor is a match (even though it involves the narrowing conversion from `size_t` to `char`), so it is used before the size+value constructor is ever considered.

So to answer the edited-in question: no, you can't create the vector without naming its type. But in C++17 you can use class template argument deduction and simply write `return std::vector(i, c);`

Comment: That makes sense, but i don't understand why initializer_list is "matched first". Could you please explain why return std::vector<char>( i, c ) works fine but std::vector<char>{ i, c } doesn't? That would be awesome. I have problems finding the relevant text passages in cppreference, that explain the differences between curly braces and usual constructor syntax.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lars Added an answer for the follow-up question too.