# Allocate vector size with list initialization (curly braces)

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

How can I do the equivalent of:

```
#include <vector>

size_t bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(bufferSize, ' ');
```

With list (curly braced) initialization?

When I try to do the following:

```
#include <vector>

size_t bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer {bufferSize, ' '};
```

It wrongly interprets `bufferSize` as the value to be stored in the first index of the container (i.e. calls the wrong `std::vector` constructor), and fails to compile due to invalid narrowing conversion from `unsigned int` (`size_t`) to `unsigned char`.

Comment: That's how brace-initialization works with `std::initializer_list` constructors. It always prefer those constructors, hence it tries to invoke it and fails

Comment: Why do you insist on doing this with "curly brace initialization"?

Comment: Basically a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775439/curly-braces-constructor-prefers-initializer-list-over-better-match-why

Comment: You cannot and it is big downside of idea "use curly brackets initialization everywhere". If would just use `bufferSize` issue would be even worse

Comment: @MaxLanghof Well, it is called uniform initialization.  One could be lead to believe it should be the preferred way to initialize an object ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Well I never quite got why C++ insisted on doing [this](https://xkcd.com/927/) to [C++ initialization](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8nn4fw/forrest_gump_learns_c/)...

Comment: @NathanOliver Related https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @OP Here is a very good talk on the nightmare of C++ initialization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Comment: @MaxLanghof because some recommend to use it everywhere as it is "safer" (does not have most vexing parse issue). In reality it is more dangerous.

Comment: Lately I've gotten into the habit of using `auto var = type(stuff);` as it is easier for me to control which constructor I want to call.  One of these days we might actually get this fixed though.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444814/is-it-good-habit-to-always-initialize-objects-with

Comment: tldr; Use `vector{...}` to initialize from a list (including 0 elements), and `vector(...)` to call all other constructors.  "Universal" doesn't mean "this is the replacement". It just means you can now list initialize on all objects, rather than just some of them.

Comment: @MaxLanghof another reason for wanting to use curly brace initialization is non-static member initialization via a default member initializer which is either a brace or equal initializer. And when a - say - `std::vector<int>` member should be constructed with a certain size, one can't just write something as compact as `std::vector<int> foo { some_size, 42 }` which actually creates the vector member with `some_size` elements which are initialized to 42.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: **you don't**.

This is not a problem with uniform initialization per se, but with `std::initializer_list`. There is a [special rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#list) in *overload resolution* that **always** gives priority to constructors taking `std::initializer_list` if *list-initialization* is used, regardless of the existence of other constructors which might require less implicit conversions.

---

I would suggest using

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(bufferSize, ' ');
```

or, if you *really* want to use *list-initialization*, create your wrapper around `std::vector` that provides constructor overloads that do the right thing.

Answer (score 7):

The two relevant overload of `std::vector` are:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()); //(1)
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); // (2)
```

These two overload has clear meaning, where the second is used to initialize the vector with the elements of the `std::initializer_list`.

Overload resolution prefer initializer-list constructors when `list-initialization` is used.

Narrowing conversions are not allowed with `list-initialization`, you're trying to create a `std::vector` with `T=unsigned char` but the deduced `T` for the `std::initializer_list` parameter is `T= unsigned long` which will involve a narrowing conversion (not allowed).