# How does auto decide the type of variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    auto n {42};
    cout << "The n has value of " << n <<
    " and a size of " << sizeof(n) << endl; // Works as expected
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    auto n = {42};
    cout << "The n has value of " << n <<
    " and a size of " << sizeof(n) << endl; // Does not work!
}
```

Why is that?
In "A Tour of C++" it is explicitly said:

> 1.4.2 Initialization
> Before an object can be used, it must be given a value. C++ offers a variety of notations for
> expressing initialization, such as the = used above, and a universal form based on curly-brace delimited initializer lists:

```cpp
    double d1 = 2.3; // initialize d1 to 2.3  
    double d2 {2.3}; // initialize d2 to 2.3  
    double d3 = {2.3}; // initialize d3 to 2.3 (the = is optional with { ... })
    complex<double> z2 {d1,d2};   
    complex<double> z3 = {d1,d2}; // the = is optional with { ... }
```

The `=` is optional with `{}`.
so, why does this happen?

Comment: It's working just fine, but `{42}` by itself is a `std::initializer_list<int>`, not an `int`. The foolproof way to create a variable that you don't get as the result of something else is `auto name = type{ args };` — and actually even that will run into issues in c++11 if the type is not move constructible (this is fixed in c++17).

Comment: Fwiw, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682992/3212865) shows the subtleties of initializer lists, initializer_lists and braced initializer lists.

Comment: "Does not work!"?  Please state how it does not work.  If there is an error, quote it (don't post a screenshot) in entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is governed by the rules of [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct), particularly [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#1) and [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/1**
>
> **Placeholder type deduction** is the process by which a type containing a
> placeholder type **is replaced by a deduced type**.
>
> **[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4**
>
> If the placeholder is the `auto` type-specifier, the deduced type `T'`
> replacing `T` is determined **using the rules for template argument
> deduction**. Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of
> `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` **or, if
> the initialization is copy-list-initialization, with
> `std​::​initializer_­list<U>`**. Deduce a value for `U` using the
> rules of template argument deduction from a function call, where `P`
> is a function template parameter type and the corresponding argument
> is `e`. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed.
> Otherwise, `T'` is obtained by substituting the deduced `U` into `P`.
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 };    // decltype(x1) is std​::​initializer_­list<int>
> auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 };  // error: cannot deduce element type
> auto x3{ 1, 2 };       // error: not a single element
> auto x4 = { 3 };       // decltype(x4) is std​::​initializer_­list<int>
> auto x5{ 3 };          // decltype(x5) is int
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Your second example is using copy-list-initialization, meaning `auto` is replaced by, using the rules for template argument deduction, `std::initializer_list<U>`, where `U` is furthermore deduced as `int`.

```
auto n {42};    // deduced type is 'int'
auto m = {42};  // deduced type is 'std::initializer_list<int>'
```

These rules particularly apply to placeholder type deduction, and does thus not apply to the case of non-placeholder types; the latter example of the op already specifies the type and non type deduction applies.

```
// no placeholder type: type is 'double', and 'd1'
// through 'd3' simply uses different ways to initialize
// an object of (non-class fundamental) type 'double'.
double d1 = 2.3;   // copy initialization
double d2 {2.3};   // direct-list initialization; no narrowing allowed
double d3 = {2.3}; // copy-list-initialization (from C++11); no narrowing allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

There is subtle difference between the two initialisation:

```
auto n {42};  // n is of type int

auto m = {42};  // m is of type initializer_list
```

[What Is a Curly-Brace Enclosed List If Not an intializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682392/what-is-a-curly-brace-enclosed-list-if-not-an-intializer-list)

`typeid` can be used to find the exact type of a variable, for example via `typeid(x).name()`

Answer (score 0):

For both cases `double d1 = {2.3};` and `auto d2 = {2.3};` the `{2.3}` is an initlaizer list.

For `double d3{2.3};` and `auto d4{2.3};` the `{2.3}` is not an initializer list.

But for the first case, you specify for `d1` what type it has, so the initializer list is used to set the value of `d1`. But for `d2` you tell the compiler to choose the type, so it will be the initializer list.

So `=` is not optional, the difference is just not directly observable if you define the type for `d1`.