# Is There a Way to Achieve Lifetime Extension by Reference Binding Apart from Inline Declaration?

Tags: c++, scope, reference, lifetime, temporary-objects

I know that I can use "Lifetime Extension Reference Binding" to keep a temporary around for the duration of the local scope `const auto& temp = "lorem ipsum"s` but I was curious if there was a way to force the duration beyond the local scope without converting it to a permenant object.

More explicitly, I'm wondering if I could do: `const auto& temp = foo();`

Attempt 1:

```
const string& foo() {
    const auto& temp = "lorem ipsum"s;
    return temp;
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
struct bar {
    const string& temp;
};

const bar foo() {
    const auto& temp = "lorem ipsum"s;
    const bar result = {temp};
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way that I haven't thought of which will let me get `temp` outside the local scope without converting it to a permanent object?

Comment: @NathanOliver attempt 1 never works either. Note the return type.

Comment: No. Just imagine if it were possible - how on earth would the compiler keep track of the object and know when to destroy it through all the references you are copying? Keep a reference count with every temporary?

Comment: @T.C. Ah yes.  For some reason I though he was returning by value.

Comment: @NathanOliver I had just learned about "Lifetime Extension by Reference Binding" and I wanted to know if I could actually further extend the temporary. As far a practical purpose, I'm just trying to understand the concept. I don't think this is a duplicate? I'm wondering if there is a way to get a reference to a temporary outside the scope it was declared in.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I knew neither of them would work. Sounds like you're saying there isn't a way to do this. Which is the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: Hopefully, the standard reference quoted in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784304/514235) is answering this Q.

Comment: @iammilind Yeah that exactly answered the question good call on the duplicate.