# Is vector<auto> not allowed ? (error: invalid use of ‘auto’)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, auto

I have:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   auto a = -SOME_CONST_MAX;
   vector<auto> myVec {a, a, a, a};
}
```

I don't know the type of the `SOME_CONST_MAX` but I want to make a vector of the type of `-SOME_CONST_MAX`. I assumed `vector<auto>` would work as it will deduce from type of `a`.

I'm getting these errors running:
`g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp`

```
main.cpp:9:9: error: invalid use of ‘auto’
  vector<auto> myVec {a, a, a, a};
         ^
main.cpp:9:13: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  vector<auto> myVec {a, a, a, a};
             ^
main.cpp:9:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
main.cpp:9:32: error: scalar object ‘myVec’ requires one element in initializer
  vector<auto> myVec {a, a, a, a};
                                ^
```

Is `vector<auto>` not allowed? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can use `vector<decltype(a)>` instead

Comment: C++17 will introduce template type deduction for class templates, so you'll be allowed to do something like `vector myVec{a,a,a,a};` and the compiler will deduce the type of `myVec` as `vector<int>`.

Comment: highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor

Comment: @Slava - very simple and elegant: IMHO, you should propose it as an answer

Comment: @max66 the problem that it is not answer to the question "Is vector<auto> not allowed?" Which probably requires reference to the C++ standard.

Comment: To note, with the Concepts TS, `std::vector<auto>` is allowed [in some contexts](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/waxJhbwnYICIqjxQ).

Comment: @chris Oh boy, why does thing needs to become more and more complex? Concepts is a great idea, but allowing `std::vector<auto> v = ...` and class template type deduction like `std::vector v = ...` will definitely not make things simpler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find Slava's solution really simple and elegant

```
vector<decltype(a)> myVec {a, a, a, a};
```

But just to show another way, you can use the `variadic` template function

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
std::vector<T> getVect (T const & t, Ts const & ... ts)
 { return { t, ts... } ; }
```

You can use `auto` again

```
auto myVec = getVect(a, a, a, a, a);
```

Answer (score 10):

If I remember correctly, proposals have been made for `vector<auto>` syntax.  They where not accepted by the C++ standard committee.

C++17 will introduce something like `std::vector bob = {a,a,a,a};` that just works.  Note the lack of `<auto>`.  This may just be the language feature, with actual use in `std` following afterward.

`auto` is also added to templates, but `auto` is *always a value* never a type.  So using `auto` to replace a type was considered a bad idea.

Here is a use of `auto` in a template:

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t=std::integral_constant<decltype(x),x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant{};
```

and now `constant<7>` is a `std::integral_constant<int,7>`.  This is considered useful for many reasons.

The answer to your practical problem using current C++ is:

```
auto a = -SOME_CONST_MAX;
std::vector<decltype(a)> myVec {a, a, a, a};
```

where we deduce the type of `a` and pass it to `vector`.