# Usefulness of std::make_pair and std::make_tuple in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

In my understanding, the sole reason for the existence of [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) and [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) is that you don't have to write the types by yourself as they are automatically deduced. In C++17, we have [template argument deduction for class templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html), which allows us to simply write

```
std::pair p(1, 2.5); // C++17
```

instead of

```
auto p = std::make_pair(1, 2.5); // C++11/14
```

The situation for [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is analogous. This leads to the following question: In C++17, is there a situation in which it is beneficial to use `std::make_pair` and `std::make_tuple` instead of using the constructors of `std::pair` and `std::tuple`?

Please, consider just pure C++17 code (i.e. no need for backward compatibility with C++14) and assume that everyone is familiar with this C++17 feature.

Comment: "Analogical" is also the title of my upcoming Vulcan adult fanfic novel. Fascinating.

Comment: `std::make_pair` decays `std::reference_wrapper<T>` to `T&`. Does the deduction guide take that into account?

Comment: I think (but am not sure) that there's a difference between constructors and `make_pair` when `std::reference_wrapper`s are involved.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry I broke your joke :)

Comment: @KerrekSB Ohhh, I just got it now 20 minutes later...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> In C++1z, is there a situation in which it is beneficial to use `std::make_pair` and `std::make_tuple` instead of using the constructors of `std::pair` and `std::tuple`?

There are always fun exceptions to every rule. What do you want to happen to `std::reference_wrapper`?

```
int i = 42;
auto r = std::ref(i);

pair p(i, r);                 // std::pair<int, std::reference_wrapper<int> >
auto q = std::make_pair(i,r); // std::pair<int, int&>
```

If you want the latter, `std::make_pair` is what you want.

---

Another situation cames in generic code. Let's say I have a template parameter pack that I want to turn into a tuple, would I write this?

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto foo(Ts... ts) {
    return std::tuple(ts...);
}
```

Now the intent of that code is to probably to get a `std::tuple<Ts...>` out of it, but that's not *necessarily* what happens. It depends on `Ts...`:

- if `Ts...` is a single object that is itself a `tuple`, you get a copy of it. That is, `foo(std::tuple{1})` gives me a `tuple<int>` rather than a `tuple<tuple<int>>`.
- if `Ts...` was a single object that is a `pair`, I get a `tuple` of those elements. That is, `foo(std::pair{1, 2})` gives me a `tuple<int, int>` rather than a `tuple<pair<int, int>>`.

In generic code, I would stay away from using CTAD for types like `tuple` because it's never clear what you're going to get. `make_tuple` doesn't have this problem. `make_tuple(tuple{1})` is a `tuple<tuple<int>>` and `make_tuple(pair{1, 2})` is a `tuple<pair<int, int>>` because that's what you asked for.

---

Additionally, since `std::make_pair` is a function template, you can pass that into another function template that maybe wants to do something:

```
foo(std::make_pair<int, int>);
```

This doesn't seem super useful, but somebody somewhere is using it to solve a problem - and you can't just pass `std::pair` there.

Comment: Similarly to `std::reference_wrapper`, you may add `make_pair` overloads (with your custom type) without fully specialized `pair` for your type.

Comment: Regarding passing constructors as function templates -- at least not until someone proposes that `std::direct_init` or whatever it was called... and then `make_from_tuple` would go away, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think [it's related](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0271r0.html)? `direct_init<T>` wouldn't work on a `tuple` (unless `T` had a `tuple` constructor).

Comment: @Barry: Couldn't you just do `pair p(i, *r);` if you want a language reference? Indeed, it would make your intent a lot more clear than the `make_pair` example; I would have expected it to use a `reference_wrapper` too.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, that'd give you `pair<int,int>` (assuming you mean like `r.get()`)

Comment: @Barry: You're right, you couldn't use it to replace passing `make_pair` as a metacallback. Never mind.

Comment: Clearly we need to be able to pass pointers-to-constructors around.  And the deduction guides for `pair` should unpack `reference_wrapper`s.  Too late now.  C++17, here she comes!

Comment: @Yakk They considered making the deduction guide unwarp and decided against it.

Comment: @T.C. Do you know how come?

Comment: Could you provide some details on how exactly the type-deduction differs between template constructors and template functions? I'm surprised that there's a difference.

Comment: @Barry Not beyond what the paper says.

Comment: @KyleStrand template constructors have deduction guides.  I am uncertain if C++17 added them to template functions, but C++14 did not have them.

Comment: @Yakk Oh, I didn't realize from the above conversation (or what I've read of the proposal) that "deduction guides" is a standardese term. Since I don't fully understand how deduction works for template constructors, would you (or Barry or TC) be willing to take a look at the ambiguity described at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39087312/1858225) and confirm or refute my understanding of the issue?

Comment: @KyleStrand That's not an answer. That's a blog post. And `auto var2 = Variable(var);` would be of type `Variable<int>`

Comment: @Barry I'm not sure I understand the criticism; it's a bit long, but not terribly long compared to other longish answers on the site, and all of the points addressed are directly in response to either the question itself or other answers that are incorrect (since so many of them say, essentially, "not only does C++ not support this, it *can't* support this, because [some example]").

Comment: @KyleStrand I stopped at "requires the use of `auto`". That's...just not true.

Comment: @T.C. You are absolutely correct, and thank you for pointing that out. Looking at the proposal again, this is completely obvious, so I'm not sure why I thought `auto` was necessary, and frankly I feel like a fool. I've completely revised the answer; fortunately Coliru supports 7.1, which has GCC 7.1.0, so I was able to actually try out my code examples this time.

Comment: Isn't the second example kind of moot? I mean, you could pass a lambda which constructs a pair, rather than `std::make_pair`.