# How to make std::array of structs initialisation more minimal?

Tags: c++

I am using test code with some test data as below. I would really like to eliminate count from the array declaration. Is it possible? Also why does double braces `= {{ ... }}` are required?

```
struct test_data {
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int turnToStop;
    int expectedResult;
};


int main()
{
    std::array<test_data, 5> tests = {{
        {{2, 1, 3}, 2020, 10},
        {{1, 2, 3}, 2020, 27},
        {{2, 3, 1}, 2020, 78},
        {{3, 2, 1}, 2020, 438},
        {{3, 1, 2}, 2020, 1836}
    }};
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to eliminate the count from `std::array` like this, but you could use a built-in array type: `test_data tests[] = { ... }`. You can still use for loops to iterate over such an array, and `std::begin()` and `std::end()` still work correctly (they have specializations for arrays).

Comment: The question does not have an answer, so it looks like there is no way with `std::array` without copying (And would also suggest that a plain C array like above, `test_data tests[] = { ... }`, is good enough)

Answer (score 0):

> I would really like to eliminate count from the array declaration. Is it possible?

With standard library, no.

There is a `make_array` that is supposed to eliminate the count when initialising std::array, but it's not standardised yet:

[Current status of std::make_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942556/current-status-of-stdmake-array/50943274#50943274)

> Also why does double braces = {{ ... }} are required?

```
{{2, 1, 3}, 2020, 10},
```

Double braces are required because the inner pair of braces are for initialising your vector `nums`

Comment: `std::make_array` would require `auto tests = make_array(test_data{{2, 1, 3}, 2020, 10}, test_data{{1, 2, 3}, 2020, 27}, ...)`, repeating the type name over and over

Comment: The op is referring to the outermost double braces

Comment: @Artyer no you can write `make_array<test_data>({...}, {...})` ... I think ... can't look into it right now

Comment: @bolov You can't since make_array takes `T&&...`, so you can't use an braced initializer lists to deduce a `T`. Also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array claims that it has been removed because of deduction guides and `std::to_array`, and I think `std::to_array<test_data>({{...}, {...}})` perfectly answers this question

Comment: The first template parameters is a special one that if provided and different than `void` is used to explicitly specify the type of the element. So it seems you can and that is by design. The `to_array` seems to have the problem of copying the elements. Again I am going only from a rudimentary reading of the documentation. Can't properly check this assertions.

Comment: @Artyer `to_array` works very nice: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5aeba9f02a3bf80. Actually that would be a perfect answer to my question, but I see question was closed.

Comment: ....but in the linked answer there seems to be no mention of std::to_array, I think it should be added there.