# How should you create a std::experimental::observer_ptr to a non-const object that cannot mutate the value it points to?

Tags: c++, constants, smart-pointers, std, c++-ts

Is this the canonical way to create a `std::experimental::observer_ptr` to a non-`const` object that cannot mutate the value it points to?

```cpp
auto i = int{0};

auto p = std::experimental::make_observer(&std::as_const(i));
*p = 1; // compilation error, as desired
```

https://godbolt.org/z/h3Uq0o

**EDIT:**

What if the pointer already exists (which I suppose is the more common use-case)? Would we have to `const_cast`?

```cpp
auto i = int{0};
auto p = &i;

auto q = std::experimental::make_observer(const_cast<const int*>(p));
*q = 1; // compilation error, as desired
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NbR6Nj

Comment: In both of these cases, `i` is not a "const object".

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, but one can infer that I mean a pointer to an object that cannot mutate the value it points to.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've edited the original question for clarity.

Comment: This might be a case for NOT using `auto` and `make_observer`, but just writing out `std::experimental::observer_ptr<const int> p`.

Comment: Does C++ even have canonical ways of doing things? Since operator & can be overloaded sometimes you may also need to write something like `auto p{ ::std::experimental::make_observer(::std::addressof(::std::as_const(i)))};`

Comment: @VTT Builtin operators cannot be overloaded.  `&` on an `int` means what it means.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't complicate matters.  Just do

```
observer_ptr<const int> p{&i};
```

And everything is fine.

You can also do this according to the [spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr/observer_ptr):

```
observer_ptr p{&std::as_const(i)};
```

but GCC and Clang seems to diverge from the spec here.  The implementation uses a qualified name for the `(element_type*)` constructor, therefore blocking class template argument deduction.

---

Much like `std::make_pair`, `make_observer` exists because the library fundamentals 2 TS is created in pre-C++17 era.  Class template argument deduction wasn't a thing at that time.  Nowadays, we rarely need a separate make function like `std::make_pair` (counterexample: reference wrappers, see [Usefulness of `std::make_pair` and `std::make_tuple` in C++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43875608)), and similarly we rarely need `make_observer`.

Therefore, it doesn't make much sense to talk about the "canonical" way of using a pre-C++17 feature like `observer_ptr` in C++17.  Granted, we can use class template argument deduction if it actually works.  That's simply not even considered in the design of `observer_ptr`.

Comment: Not using CTAD with the smart pointer construction helpers in the STL (```std::make_unique``` and ```std::make_shared```) is a hard habit to break and was the source of the confusion in this case. You're right that there is no need for a helper when constructing a 'dumb' smart pointer like ```std::observer_ptr```.

Comment: I'll happily accept your answer if you highlight the difference between ```std::observer_ptr``` and the existing smart pointers as it pertains to CTAD and the ```std::make_``` helpers.

Comment: @invexed I don’t think this has much to do with smart / dumb pointers whatsoever.  The reason that the smart pointers disable CTAD is there is no good way of differentiating pointers obtained from new and new[] and also make_shared can allocate once.  `observer_ptr` is based on C++14, so it doesn’t make much sense to talk about CTAD on it I suppose?

Comment: There is still a difference between ```observer_ptr``` and the other smart pointers in that you can use CTAD with the former but can't with the latter (which led to my question in the first place). I will accept your answer though; people can read these comments if need be. Thanks.

Comment: @invexed `observer_ptr` isn't in the standard, so it isn't updated for C++17 ...

Comment: I thought your answer was showing CTAD: ```observer_ptr p{&std::as_const(i)};```, but I've just tested it and indeed, CTAD doesn't work with ```observer_ptr```. Perhaps you should edit your answer so that it doesn't look like the template argument is being deduced?

Comment: @invexed I said, "GCC seems to diverge from the spec here. The implementation uses a qualified name for the `(element_type*)` constructor, therefore blocking class template argument deduction."

Comment: I am using Clang, not GCC; ```observer_ptr``` is not CTAD-enabled with Clang either. For that reason, I think ```make_observer``` is a perfectly reasonable way of creating an ```observer_ptr``` if you don't need to explicitly specify whether or not the pointer can modify the value it points to.

Comment: @invexed OK, seems the source in libstdc++ and libc++ are the same.