# c++ : using parameter pack in constructors?

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic, parameter-pack

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
    public: 

    A(bool b, int i)
        : b_(b) , i_(i) {}

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << b_ << " " << i_ << "\n"; 
    }

    private:

        bool b_;
        int i_;
};

class B 
{
    public: 

    B(double d)
        : d_(d) {}

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << d_ << "\n"; 
    }

    private:

        double d_;
};

template<class T=A, typename ... Args>
void f(int a, Args ... args)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    T t(args...);
    t.print();
}

int main()
{
    f(1,false,3);
    f<A>(2,true,1);
    f<B>(3,2.0);
}
```

The code above compiles and runs fine. But:

```
// (class A and B declared as above)   

template<class T, typename ... Args>
class F 
{
 public:
  F(int a, Args ... args)
  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    T t(args...);
    t.print();
  }
};

int main()
{
    F<A>(4,true,1);
    F<B>(5,2.0);
}
```

fails to compile with message :

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:64:18: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘F::F(int, bool, int)’
>        F(4,true,1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, your instantiation of `F<A>` makes the `Args` template argument *empty*, which means the constructor only have the `a` argument, not `args`.

It seems that you want only the *constructor* to have a template parameter pack, not the whole class:

```
template<class T>
class F 
{
 public:
  template<typename ... Args>
  F(int a, Args ... args)
  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    T t(args...);
    t.print();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You made the class a template, not the constructor.

But only the constructor "knows" what the template arguments should be, because those are deduced from the *constructor* arguments.

[That doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/984394/4386278).

Instead, you can make the *constructor* a template, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your needs, it should be:

```
template<class T, typename ... Args>
class F 
{
 public:
  F(int a, Args ... args)
  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    T t(args...);
    t.print();
  }
};

int main()
{
    F<A, bool, int>(4,true,1);
    F<B, double>(5,2.0);
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
class F 
{
 public:
  template <typename ... Args>
  F(int a, Args ... args)
  {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    T t(args...);
    t.print();
  }
};

int main()
{
    F<A>(4,true,1);
    F<B>(5,2.0);
}
```