# No matching constructor for initialization of variadic template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to learn `Variadic templates` and have no clue why this won't compile, the error is:
`no matching constructor for initialization of 'test<>'`.

While we are at it, I like to ask a second question by clarifying my comments within the code.

```
template <typename ...Args>     // this is just how Variadic template are defined
class test {
 public:
 int arr[sizeof...(Args)];       // this is packing or unpacking? why are 
                                 // dots outside of bracket?

 test(Args... arg)               // this is called packing?
               : arr{arg...}{}   // this is called un-packing?
};

int main(){
 test<> t(1,2,3);
 return 0;
}
```

Edit: seems like i need to do `test <int, int, int>`, but why do I have to as this other example works as is:

```
template <typename ...Args> 
int func(Args... arg)
{
   int a[] = {arg...};
   return sizeof...(arg);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << func(1,2,3,4,5,6) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

func doesn't need the `<int, int ,int..` part.

Comment: `t` is of type `test<>` - an instantiation of `test` template with empty `Args` pack. Therefore, its constructor takes no arguments.

Comment: So how do I fix it to take in the passed parameters?

Comment: You probably want `test<int, int, int> t(1,2,3)`.

Comment: `sizeof...` is a single operator, the dots are not something additional or separate.  There's documentation for this stuff around. >_>

Comment: With sufficiently modern compiler, you can write `test t(1,2,3);` This automatically deduces `Args` to be `int, int, int`

Comment: I have added another example.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example does not work because you need to specify types like:

```cpp
int main() {
    test<int, int, int> t(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are able to use C++17, you can take advantage of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and have something like:

```cpp
int main() {
   test t(1,2,3);
   return 0;
}
```

But prior to C++17, *class template argument deduction* **did not** exist. However, *function template argument deduction* existed. That's why your second example works without explicitly specifying template types.