# Why would optional garbage collection be useful in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Garbage Collection in C++ — why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228620/garbage-collection-in-c-why)

At Going Native 2012 today during *Interactive Panel: The Importance of Being Native* there was some talk about the future potential of C++ getting a garbage collector. Herb Sutter alluded of it's potential benefits, specifically for a linked list implementations, but wasn't specific. My impression *was* that RAII is a better/more optimal idiom than automatic garbage collection. What benefits could garbage collection have in modern C++?

Comment: Just watch the video feed and he specifically stated what he thought was an ideal canidate for GC.  I was there too :)

Comment: Herb Sutter was probably referring to lock-free linked lists, which require garbage collection, or at least code that amounts to it.

Comment: "My impression was that RAII is a better/more optimal idiom than automatic garbage collection". I have no idea what gave you that impression. RAII can be used to mostly automate scope-based reference counting but that has been regarded as suboptimal for 50 years which is why all modern production garbage collectors use tracing collection and not reference counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One advantage of garbage collection is that it lets you batch the object deallocations, and have them happen when convenient from a performance standpoint.

It also is more-or-less immune to programmer mistakes causing memory leaks - you have to be clever to escape a garbage collector, and if you were clever you could manage memory explicitly.